# Is it safe to cast between a function pointer and a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have would like to be able to treat a method declared as `void T::f()` as `void (*)(T*)`.  Is this a valid conversion (ie can it be safely called and the first argument will be put into `this`)?

Comment: Short answer, no.

Comment: Use a lambda to do the trick: `[](T* t){ t->f(); }`